# Error while loading bquant package in r

Tags: r

I installed BQuant package in my windows system.When I loaded the package it showed the  following error **Error: package ‘BQuant’ is not installed for 'arch=i386'**    .    Can anyone  please sort it out.If not is there any other packages for NMR analysis in R.

Comment: Have you followed the instructions at http://www.stat.purdue.edu/~ovitek/BQuant-Web/Installation.htm? Also, post the results of `sessionInfo()` into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Since according to your recent other question you are only interested in a good peak detection algorithm, you could get the code of the relevant functions directly from the package source (look in folder R inside the zip).